# How do I operate List async by using Dart？

Tags: asynchronous, flutter, dart, async-await

I have a collection, and now I need to iterate through the data in it, and then modify one of the fields, but this modification process is time consuming and requires asynchronous, I do not know how to write this code correctly.

Here are my fake code：

```dart
Stream<int> asynchronousNaturalsTo(int n) async* {
    yield calculate(n).asStream();
  }

  Future<int> calculate(int i) async {
    // async calculate result. maybe there is some long-running operate.
    return Future.value(i + 10);
  }

  main() async {
    // 1. I have a List that contains data needs be calculated by async.
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      // 2. calculate
      var list = await asynchronousNaturalsTo(i);
      // 3. finally, use the final result.
      print(list);
    }
  }
```

How do I write the code?
thx...

Comment: do you mean you don't want to use await keyword and want to make calculation asynchronous ??

Comment: @KalpeshKundanani No, I know the async calculation must use await. I just want to   operate the data in list by async.

Comment: so if you have `N` elements in your `List` then you want to apply `N` async operations (on each element) and afterwards to wait for each operation to complete? if so, what about `Future.forEach()` / `Future.any()`?

Comment: @pskink Yes this is what i mean, let me try the way you say first

Comment: yure welcome, write a self answer then...